# using keras's .flow_from_directory() on mounted s3 bucket in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, amazon-s3, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a convolutional neural network in databricks using Spark 2.4.4 and a Scala 2.11 backend in python. I have build CNN's before but this is my first time with using Spark(databricks) and AWS s3. 
The files in AWS are oredered like this:

- train_test_small/(train or test)/(0,1,2 or 3)/

And then a list of images in every directory corresponding to their category(0,1,2,3)

In order to access my files stored in the s3 bucket I mounted the bucket to databricks like this:

```
# load in the image files
WS_BUCKET_NAME = "sensored_bucket_name/video_topic_modelling/data/train_test_small"
MOUNT_NAME = "train_test_small"
dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s" % AWS_BUCKET_NAME, "/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME)
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME))
```

Upon using: `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())` I can see the bucket mounted to:

`MountInfo(mountPoint='/mnt/train_test_small', source='sensored_bucket_name/video_topic_modelling/data/train_test_small', encryptionType='')`

I then try to access this mounted directory through keras's flow_from_directory() module using the following piece of code:

```
# create extra partition of the training data as a validation set
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input, validation_split=0) #included in our dependencies

# set scaling to most common shapes
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/mnt/train_test_small',
                                                 target_size=(320, 240),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=96,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 subset='training')
                                                 #shuffle=True)
validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/mnt/train_test_small',
                                                 target_size=(320, 240),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=96,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 subset='validation')
```

However this gives me the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/train_test_small/train/'`

I tried to figure this out using keras and databricks documentation but got no further. My best guess at the moment right now is that the keras flow_from_directory() is unable to detect mounted directories but I am not sure.

Anyone out there who does know how to apply the .flow_from_directory() module on a s3 mounted directory in databricks or who knows a good alternative? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be missing one more directory level indication to the flow_from_directory. From Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

**directory**: string, path to the target directory. It should contain **one subdirectory per class**. Any PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator.

```
# set scaling to most common shapes
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/mnt/train_test_small/train', # <== add "train" folder
    target_size=(320, 240),
    ...

validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/mnt/train_test_small/test', # <== add "test" folder
    target_size=(320, 240),
    ....
```

Comment: Hi, sadly this results in the error: ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/train_test_small/train'```. However I was thinking maybe it has to do with the relativity of this path where the notebook would not be in the same directory as the mnt folder? However I am yet to figure out in which folder the current notebook would be in relative to the mounted path

Comment: It was indeed this problem: the direct path to the folder includes /dbfs/mnt/train_test_small/train/ which is strange since the mounted directory output suggests using /dbfs:/

Answer (score 0):

Answer found. To access the direct path to the folder add /dbfs/mnt/train_test_small/train/